# How can I locate my Internet browsing history?

Tags: windows-7, browser

I need to look back at the HISTORY of what I have looked at over the last few days, but try as I might, I can't find how I access the HISTORY.

I am forgetful and just wasted hours trying to find a site where I put items in the basket but was too tired to complete the purchase (I think!!). But I can't even remember the site to return to it now.

How can I locate my Internet browsing history?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You question needed some improvement, so I made some edits to fit the format of this site. You were not exactly clear, but your description lead me to believe you were asking about Internet browsing history. If I am wrong, you can rollback my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a web browser, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> should work in most of them.